# Graphics issues with Ubuntu 17.10 and Kaby Lake integrated graphics

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, 17.10, intel

I recently updated my machine from Ubuntu 17.04 (which worked very well with no graphics related issues at all) to 17.10, and my computer has had all sorts of issues.

Issue 1: when I put my computer to sleep and wake up, I get this weird glitch where every 10-15 seconds my computer tries to go back to sleep. (screen goes black, I have to tap a key on my keyboard for it to wake back up). This glitch does not go away unless I restart my machine.

Issue 2: connecting/disconnecting additional monitors also causes similar behavior as issue 1 where it goes to sleep and then does so again every 10-15 seconds until I disconnect the monitor and restart the machine.

I've done a bit of research and it looks like it may have something to do with the fact that I have Intel Integrated Graphics (Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)) and that the graphics are not updated for the 17.10 release. If this is still true, what are my options? If there are no options, what would you recommend doing to revert back to 17.04?

Comment: If you need "downgrade" - hopefully not - it has to be to 16.04. 17.04 will be out of support soon.